# Google Maps - Unable to locate Zoom In/Out elements

Tags: android, junit, automated-tests, appium

I'm testing an app where I need to zoom 4x to reach to a particular District.

I've used the following xpath:

```
 @FindBy(xpath= "//android.widget.ImageView[@content-desc='Zoom in']")
 WebElement btnZoomIn;
```

But, I get the below error:

```
 An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
```

I also tried using

```
  List<WebElement> listImageView = driver.findElements(By.className(("android.widget.ImageView")));
```

But, listImageView.size() returns 0

Below is UIAutomatorViewer screenshot:

[image]

Please help me with a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a workaround to the problem.

The problem was that before the map loaded, I used to get Android Location Permission alert. When I clicked on "Yes", the map got loaded. 
But the driver was unable to find the elements. 
So, I updated my Appium driver from 1.6.3 to 1.6.4; and added

capabilities.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", true);

After which no alert for Permissions were displayed and I was able to get the control elements for Google Maps.

What I still can't figure out is how the permission alert affected the visibility of elements on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

As per the view hierarchy I see that one of the parent element is listed with the class name 'android.support.v4.widget.Drawerlayout' witch is used in the lower versions of the android.

If you are automating your app for lower version of the Android try running the test with the driver running in Selendroid mode. Which can be set with the following additional desired capability:

> capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME,
>   AutomationName.SELENDROID);

or

> capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "Selendroid");

Comment: I'm automating it for the newer versions. I had a talk with the developer and he said that the layout is built using android fragments. Could that be an issue? I did not find enough details on whether appium supports Fragments or not.

Comment: We also have the Google map integration in our map. Here I am able to successfully access the 'My Location' button.
But the search results displayed in the attached image [![Google_Search_Results][1]][1]  are not identifiable even by the UI Automator. So I guess some of the elements of the Google Map activity are not directly accessible by UI Automation. 
However I am able to click successfully on the search result using the relative location of the results with the search bar, which is part of the layout of the overall screen.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SS2vu.png